# Threads to Parallel For exchange

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

I need exchange my program with Threads to parallel for loop, but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is my code with threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    obj[i] = new Object((i + 1) * sizeForOneThread, 400, i *  
    sizeForOneThread, 0, scaled, 400);
    thread[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj[i].generateFractal));
    thread[i].Start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    thread[i].Join();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx) might be a good start.

```
Parallel.For(0, 4, i =>
{
    obj[i] = new Object((i + 1) * sizeForOneThread, 400, i * sizeForOneThread, 0, scaled, 400);
    obj[i].generateFractal();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Updated.